# Index out of range when trying to retrieve userPrincipalName from AD

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm stumped..

I'm trying to get the userPrincipalName from AD as follows:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://DCHS");
search.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", UserName);
SearchResult result = search.FindOne();    
DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
_UPN = entry.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0].ToString();
```

But this gives me:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

EDIT:
This code gets the SSID of the current user.  I need to make this work on any user I enter into a text box.

```
WindowsIdentity windowsId = new WindowsIdentity(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token);
_SSID = windowsId.User.ToString()
```

Comment: Is it entry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value ?

Comment: The code looks fine, my only question would be is there a property called "userPrincipalName" in the DirectoryEntry that is returned?

Comment: It's happening because `entry.Properties["userPrincipalName"]` doesn't contain anything.  I would recommend taking Bala R's advice and doing a check before accessing it.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it so I can get to the WindowsIdentity of the user entered..   It works if I'm the logged in user, however when I throw someone elses username at it, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is because you are treating the userPrincipalName entry as an array of values.  Try modifying your code as follows:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://DCHS");
search.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", UserName);
SearchResult result = search.FindOne();    
DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
_UPN = entry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value.ToString();
```

Notice that I changed the last line from [0] to Value.  That should fix your issue.

The one thing I would say is that I would do some checking before trying to read this value.  There are cases where a user wouldn't have a UPN.  In that case, the code would throw an error when you tried to access the field (the field wouldn't exist so it wouldn't be that you just need to make sure it isn't null).

Comment: The Properties Property of the DirectoryEntry object is a PropertyCollection and each of the Items in the PropertyCollection is a PropertyValueCollection. Using the indexer [0] isn't necessarily wrong in this case.  Properties["userPrincipalName"] will return a PropertyValueCollection using the indexer [0] will return the first object in that collection.

Comment: @GunnerL3510 - Hmmm, I guess you are right.  However, wouldn't that return different information based upon which fields are contained in the collection or is the item value entry always at position zero?

Comment: @BiggsTRC If I remember correctly, and I probably don't, if the Property of the DirectoryEntry that you are accessing will only ever have one object in its PropertyValueCollection it will always be at index 0 and can be accessed by using the Value Property.  However, if there is more than one object in the PropertyValueCollection, if you attempt to access the Value Property it will either throw an exception, or return the PropertyValueCollection as a whole.  Don't quote me on that, it's been a while since I've run into this situation and had to deal with it.

Comment: Having changed it to your suggestion, I now receive `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @Matt - in that case, you aren't finding a user or your user doesn't have a UPN.

Comment: @BiggsTRC Well I know the user exists, and if I have a UPN, then they must have one also

Comment: @Matt - Assuming someone else has a UPN because you do is a faulty assumption.  I just accidentally created a batch of test users without UPNs.  Why don't you try finding your record?

Comment: While I agree with you, I find it hard to believe out of all the users I've tested, I'm the only one that has a UPN..

Comment: Ok.. I searched even more people, and discovered (after searching about 15) that some people have a UPN and some don't.. ahhhh!!!  I don't suppose you know another way I could obtain the WindowsIdentity of an arbitrary user?

Comment: SAMAccountName will be the login name that they use.  Active Directory knows them by their GUID (regardless of what attributes they have).  What exactly are you looking for this information for (it will help with the identification of what you are looking for)?  One thing you could do is open up your AD console and go to a user and read through the Attributes (I believe) tab, where every tag is listed.  You can find exactly what you are looking for and then verify if all users have it.

Comment: I'm after the users SSID that comes in the form of `S-1-5-21-2222111111-6443232211-1133445544-12345`  See the original post for the code I use to get this for the current user

Comment: @Matt - The attribute you are looking for is `objectSid`  Put that in your Properties brackets and you should get the SID.

Comment: @BiggsTRC  I could kiss you.. Thankyou so much.. I originally saw objectSid in the list of properties, but ignored it because it said it was a byte.. I didn't bother to google it!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find user by name
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(UserName);

if(user != null)
{
    string upn = user.UserPrincipalName;
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do to avoid the exception (if that's valid) is to do

```
if (entry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Count > 0)
{
    _UPN = entry.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0].ToString();
}
```

but if you were supposed to get a valid result and you aren't then I would check the LDAP connection string and such. There are a few LDAP browsers that you could use (commercial + trial) to get your connection string right.

Comment: When an AD field is not populated, in some cases it won't even exist.  For example, I put the Employee ID in the field employeeID.  However, if I haven't populated that field for a user, even your above code would throw an error because the property would not be included in the array.  In that case, you would still get an index exception error.

Comment: I believe the field is populated, since if I use my own username, then the code works, if I use a different username, then it fails..

Comment: Could it be that the user account that you are using to run this doesmnot have enough privileges to query other users?